# Source from which dynamic CRM 2011 data is edited

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, requiredfieldvalidator

In CRM 2011, a CRM user modified a contact information. I can check that through audit logs the changes that the user made.

Now the user modified the First Name and Last Name of the Contact (required fields in CRM) to blank. Now I know that this is not possible through CRM form as the fields are required in the form.

Also there is no JS or any other code written on the form that can disable that required functionality.

I want to know from where these records have been modified in MS CRM.

Also tracing is been disabled in CRM so we do not have logs for this edit :-(

Any help in this regards will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

These fields do not need to be updated on a CRM form directly. They can be updated in various ways. Common suspects are:

1. Custom plugins
2. Workflows
3. External parts accessing the Organization.svc or OrganizationData.svc endpoints

In all scenerio's the Business Required constraint is bypassed. In CRM plugins and workflows can actually act on behalf of the user and doing so it appears as if the user modified affected records himself directly.

Comment: also a data import (export/import excel file) can bypass the form checks